# Determine hyperlink to display based on client's browser

Tags: hyperlink, browsers

Is it possible to display a different hyperlink based on whether user is viewing the page from which the link is on in IE, Edge, or Chrome?

Use case:  We are using a vendor-based app that works well in Chrome and Edge but not so well in IE.  We'd like to detect which browser the user is hitting the link from and,

IF using IE, use a link that has the "microsoft-edge..." prefix on the URL. ELSE, use a link without that prefix.

I'm guessing there is some sort of javascript that could do this but not sure and not a super-techy user.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 for about two more weeks...then it'll be SharePoint Online.

Comment: You can detect which browser is being used using JavaScript & then embed the hyperlinks using Script editor or content editor web part (classic experience) on SharePoint page. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505966/determine-what-browser-being-used-using-javascript) for browser detection.